# Using node_xslt for Transformations

Tags: node.js, xslt-1.0

I am trying to use [node_xslt](https://github.com/bsuh/node_xslt/blob/master/README.md) for transforming an XML file to another XML file. I have no clue what those parameters that should be passed into 'tranform' function... If someone knows how to use node_xslt, please explain what those parameters are. As mentioned in the ReadMe.md ,

```
transformedString = xslt.transform(stylesheet, document, parameters);
   // transform
   // Arguments:
   //  * stylesheet: stylesheet object
   //  * document: document object
   //  * parameters: an array of parameters to be passed to the stylesheet. length must be multiple of 2.
   //        Example: ['param1Name', 'param1Value', 'param2Name', 'param2Value']
```

what are these parameters, passed as the third one?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation regarding PI Parameters:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XSLT/PI_Parameters

It's basically allows you to pass parameters to a stylesheet when executing it